# Does the Expectation of the random variable $X^{-1}Y^{-1}Z$require that we know the joint density of $X^{-1}Y^{-1}Z$?

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Does the Expectation of the random variable $X^{-1}Y^{-1}Z$require that we know the joint density of $X^{-1}Y^{-1}Z$ or is the joint density of XYZ enough?

Comment: Could you perhaps clarify your question? What are $X$, $Y$, and $Z$? Density joint with what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Law Of The Unconcious Statistician (LOTUS), knowing the joint density of X,Y and Z will be enough. In fact, note that from the joint density of X,Y and Z you can compute the density of the random variable $X^{-1}Y^{-1}Z$
(This gives you a hint of why LOTUS is true). Sometimes you can derive densities of transformations of random variables from first principles. For the general case, see proposition 1.8 in Shao, Mathematical Statistics:

[image]